# Linking Discord, Twitter, Twitch, YouTube etc to your account

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm rather new to identity & currently writing an MVC application which is a place where you can link multiple accounts into one place to be displayed for other users to see. Basically what discord has in the settings called 'Connections', you log into multiple external logins & link them up with your account.

The only issue is I don't know the correct way to do this. I was thinking of creating multiple authentications & a cookie for each authentication or writing code to call each providers API's & logging in that way.

Please tell me if I'm heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: People could only provide opinion based answers to your question. Your question will most likely get locked. Technically there is no "correct" way to do anything in software development. You are discussing something known as "Single Sign In" A.K.A "SSO". Try doing some Google searches for SSO with .NET.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for but I didn't know it had a specific name.

Comment: No problem, it's most commonly known as "Single Sign On" or SSO...I wrote "Single Sign In" in my first comment. Either way you will get search results for either term. There are some pretty good platforms for SSO that are commonly used in industry (from my experience) but they are not free. I didn't want to promote them here. They're easy to find through search though, although I am guessing you probably want to build your own.